# How to deploy Commerce and Spartacus to ccv2

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

Currently we are using CCV2 platform, and we we are able to deploy the commerce.,

We are planning to move few of locally developed Spartacus pages, to CCV2.

Please guide how we can move both Spartacus and Commerce code bases and doing the performing build and deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look on the article below that should enlighten you on how to accomplish this:

https://www.sap.com/cxworks/article/486232623/build_and_deploy_your_first_sap_commerce_cloud_project